# Why is the order of execution of attribute assignments failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I am passing these parameters to a controller:

```
{
  "utf8" => "✓",
  "authenticity_token" => "ersjaJ4/ieZelVifP/YpBHTJtiQ53HgO5KYjEdW0BlQ=",
  "transaction" => {
    "use_balance" => "1",
    "traces_attributes" => {
      "trace_ids" => ["6"],
      "6" => {
        "amount" => "12.0",
        "charge_id" => "6"
      }
    },
    "positive_balance" => "12",
    "property_id" => "2",
    "community_id" => "1"
  },
  "commit" => "Save Payment",
  "community_id" => "1",
  "property_id" => "2"
}
```

The `controller#create` then:

```
@payment = Transaction.new(params[:transaction])
```

Then the Transaction model:

```
belongs_to :property
belongs_to :community
attr_accessible :positive_balance

def traces_attributes=(params)
  #INSIDE HERE THE VALUES OF
  #params[:trace_ids] => ['6'] OK
  #BUT
  #self.possitive_balance => "" **NOT OK**
  #self.property_id => nil **NOT OK**
end
```

My hypothesis is that `traces_attribute=` is executed before `positive_balance=` and `property_id`

Can I change this?
Why is this failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the assignments should be the same as the order of the params in the form, but I don't think this is guaranteed.

A safer solution would be to only store the data in the `traces_attributes=` method, and access the other attributes later, for example in a `before_save` [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Answer (score 0):

it looks based on the transaction hash that the property_id is outside of that hash so if you are building based on transactions it won't have a property_id

```
"transaction"=>{"use_balance"=>"1",
                "traces_attributes"=>{"trace_ids"=>["6"],
                                      "6"=>{"amount"=>"12.0",
                                            "charge_id"=>"6"
                                            }
                                      },
                "positive_balance"=>"12",
                "property_id"=>"2",
                "community_id"=>"1"
 },
"commit"=>"Save Payment",
"community_id"=>"1",
"property_id"=>"2"}
```

do you see what i mean, the number of curly braces is messed up and prop. id isn't ending up in transactions ( i just copy and pasted your code pasted above )

Comment: Yes, I understand that.
The point is that possitive_balance is indeed accessible through traces_attributes= since this attr is inside transaction, and in the hash you can see that possitive_balance is inside transaction.

Thats why im using self and not params